# How to retrieve data from multiple tables using laravel query building

Tags: php, laravel, selectquerybuilder

I have 2 records in each table. when i tried this below query

```
$result = DB::table('table1')
          ->join('table2','table1.user_id','=', 'table2.user_id')
          ->join('table3','table1.user_id','=', 'table3.user_id')
          ->join('table4','table1.user_id','=', 'table4.user_id')
          ->select('table1.*','table2.email','table3.*','table4.*')
          ->get();
```

i got the repeated data from the last table alone and also i couldn't get the data from first three tables

I need an output like this

```
--------------------------------
id      email           user_id
--------------------------------
1       aaa@test.com    40
2       bbb@test.com    40
1       ccc@test.com    40
2       ddd@test.com    40
1       eee@test.com    40
2       fff@test.com    40
1       ggg@test.com    40
2       hhh@test.com    40
--------------------------------
```

Comment: You didn't define the fields that you were looking for simply use `select` within the eloquent

Comment: still it remains to show the same @Uchiha

Comment: Define specific fields it seems you have used `inner join` over here and you might have that much understanding what output you were looking for, or  you simply post your Table Schema with expected output

Comment: i have 2 records in each table and each table have field "user_id"  I need an output to display all the records from all the table @Uchiha

Comment: you need to add a groupby('table1.user_id')

Comment: no i want to display data from all the tables @astroanu

Comment: to prevent repeated rows you need to group them by something :) you can create a new column name 'group' by concatenating two values from different fields then groupBy('group')

Comment: Not only about repeating data, I couldn't retrieve data from first 3 tables. @astroanu

Comment: I am getting data from fourth table alone repeatedly @astroanu

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue, but if the column names are same in all those tables, repeated columns with same name won't appear

Comment: but i dont why only single table data alone displaying leaving other 3 tables